# Issue with namespaces in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

```
...
using System.Xml;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        XmlDocument activeDoc=new XmlDocument();
        public Form2(string path)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(sender),Convert.ToString(e));
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            save(path);
        }
        private void save(string path){
            activeDoc.Save(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Why does button1_click function say "'path' element is not availiable in this context"?
I am sure that Form2 receives 'path', because diagnostic messages with path do work.

Comment: Because it doesn't, path is a parameter for `save` and the constructor only - See [Scopes MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the path to a class variable within constructor as follows, Note that parameters of Methods/Constructor are only accessible within that method/constructor's context. Not accessible out side of their boundary.

```
string pathString = string.Empty;

XmlDocument activeDoc=new XmlDocument();
public Form2(string path)
{
   pathString = path;
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must Declare path somewhere in your Project..do like this

```
...

    using System.Xml;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
    {
        public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
            XmlDocument activeDoc=new XmlDocument();
            String path;
            public Form2(string _path)
            {
                path = _path;
                InitializeComponent();
            }


            private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(sender),Convert.ToString(e));
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                save(path);
            }
            private void save(string path){
                activeDoc.Save(path);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `_path` still doesn't exist in `button_Click` nor does your answer answer the question "Why does button1_click function say "'path' element is not availiable in this context"?"

Comment: Your path is just in Constructor as parameter..So it's scope is just only for 
public Form2(string path)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Comment: I would note that your naming convention is not as per normal, where the local class variable would often have the underscore rather than the passed in parameter.

Answer (score -1):

There is no field path in class Form2. It can be static field of another class from this namespace for example. Constructor and save method take "path" as just local parameter

Answer (score -1):

Change your code like this

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        XmlDocument activeDoc=new XmlDocument();
        static  string  Localpath=null;
        public Form2(string path)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Localpath=path;
        }
```

.....

Now

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            save(Localpath);
        }
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the question "Why does button1_click function say "'path' element is not availiable in this context"?"

Comment: Moreover, why is your `Localpath` field static?